# Gotenberg img convertion for pdf size opimization

Tags: python, image, pdf, gotenberg

I use https://gotenberg.dev/ docker image for converting html with img to pdf.

I have a webp image of reasonable size.

I generate pdf with pyhon code like

```
with io.BytesIO() as tmp_index_html:
    tmp_index_html.write(b"""
<html>
<head>
  <title>My img</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img href="img.webp" />
</body>
</html>        
    """)
    tmp_index_html.seek(0)
    with open(img_webp, "rb") as img_webp:
        response = requests.post(
            HTML_TO_PDF_URL,
            files={
                "index.html": tmp_index_html,
                "img.webp": img_webp,
            },
            timeout=2400,
        )
 with open("resulf.pdf", "wb") as pdf:
      pdf.write(response.content)
```

The problem is that size of pdf is rather bigger then size of oroginal webp.

I found that webp is not something native for pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Imaging_model
=> I gess img is converted converted while "printing to pdf" with not the best for size optimization params.

Question: how should i preprocess my image to get reasonable small size of pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research on the issue.
The specific solution to your question is to convert the **webp** to another format
I tried converting to **jpg** and got the same size in pdf relative to the original image in **jpg**, but relative to **webp** the size increased by 2 times, which is ultimately reasonable.
The format is relatively new and may not be well supported by all applications.